# How non mapreduce applications work in YARN?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, bigdata

By using YARN, we can run non mapreduce application.

But how it works?

In HDFS, All gets stored in Blocks. For each blocks one mapper tasks would get create to process whole dataset.

But Non mapreduce applications, how it will process the datasets in different data node with out using mapreduce?

Please explain me.

Answer (score 2):

Do not confuse the Map reduce paradigm with other applications like for instance Spark. Spark can run under Yarn but does not use mappers or reducers.

Instead it uses executors, these executors are aware of the datalocality, the same way mapreduce is.

The spark Driver will start executors on data nodes and will try to keep the data locality in mind when doing so.

Also do not confuse Map Reduce default behaviour with standard behaviour. you do not **need** to have 1 mapper per input split.

Also HDFS and Map Reduce are two different things. HDFS is just the storage layer while Map Reduce handles processing.